# Unity: accessing generated SVG sprites programmatically

Tags: unity-game-engine, svg

I imported an SVG image (acd.svg) in my project that sits in "Resources/svgs". Selecting the SVG, the Importer settings opens in the Inspector where I have selected the option "Vector Sprite" as "Generated Asset Sprite".
I can succesfully drop the SVG sprite in the scene (in my case in a Canvas and it is correctly visible) and the Sprite Renderer component gets the Sprite field set to acdSprite.

Now, I would like to change programmatically the Sprite in this "SymbolObject" component but I fail to understand where the acdSprite is located.

I tried something like:

> symbolObject.GetComponent().sprite = (Sprite)
>   Resources.Load ("svgs/acd");

but I get an InvalidCastException .
My question is: How can I access the acdSprite in Unity code programmatically?

I'm using Unity 2019.1.0f2 and the SVG support seems to work quite fine

[image: svv]

Answer (score 0):

Give it a go lad.

```cs
function Start() {
    GetComponent(SpriteRenderer).sprite = image;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what is image ?

Comment: "image" is just a placeholder; replace it with your image ("svgs/acd").

Answer (score 0):

Pass the Reference of Imported SVG File through Public Gameobject in unity.

```
 public GameObject svgImage;
 private void LoadsvgImage()
    {
    Sprite sprite = svgImage.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite;

    }
```